# how to refresh fragment when MediaPlayer recreate

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I am working on the music player and I have a mini-player(fragment) in my app to control the song, in a mini player fragment, there is a text view for display the song name. I am using sharedprefrences for the store last song name in my service class and I am retrieving song name in mini_player fragment and giving that value to my text view in on resume() method of the fragment. but when the song is completed and the new song starts playing in service, this text view is not refreshing.
code:

in-service class:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getSharedPreferences(LAST_MUSIC,MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(MUSIC_FILES,uri.toString());
        editor.putString(SONG_NAME,musicFiles.get(position).getTitle());
        editor.putInt("POSITION",position);
        editor.apply();
   mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),uri);
```

mini_player fragment class:

```
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences(LAST_MUSIC,MODE_PRIVATE);
        SavedPosition=preferences.getInt("POSITION",0);
        String path=preferences.getString(MUSIC_FILES,null);
        String song_name=preferences.getString(SONG_NAME,null);
        if(path!=null){
            SHOW_MINI_PLAYER=true;
            PATH_TO_FRAG=path;
            SONG_NAME_TO_FRAG=song_name;
        }
        else {
            SHOW_MINI_PLAYER=false;
            PATH_TO_FRAG=null;
            SONG_NAME_TO_FRAG=null;
        }

//applying value


            byte[] art=getAlbumArt(PATH_TO_FRAG);
            if(art!=null){
              Glide.with(getContext()).load(art).into(mini_img);
            }
            else {
            Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.headphones).into(mini_img);
            }

            mini_nm.setText(SONG_NAME_TO_FRAG);
        }
```

above  SHOW_MINI_PLAYER, PATH_TO_FRAG, SONG_NAME_TO_FRAG is public static final variables

Comment: Use `Bundle` instead of `SharedPreferences`. `SharedPreferences` is not intended for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Because you render track data one time in `onResume()` method. You have to listen to `SharedPreferences` changes and redraw data.

call this in `onResume()` method of fragment    `getSharedPreferences(LAST_MUSIC,MODE_PRIVATE).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`

dont forget to call `unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in `onPause()` method of fragment